# Convenient way to populate fields in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter has a very convenient way to repopulate the field on validation failure

```
set_value()
```

In my app I want allow user to edit the entity using the same form I use to create it. But I cannot use `set_value()` to populate the fields while the form is in editing mode.

I there any convenient way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: why can't you use `set_value`?

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You give `set_value()` a second parameter that will be its initial value on loading.

I generally do this using a `@` to supress errors if the piece of data does not exist

```
set_value('input_name',@$input_value);
```

for this, the form element will be prefilled with `$input_value` if it exists

Answer (score 0):

You should use `set_value`. I don't see how you would get an error using `set_value` when editing.

`set_value` has a second parameter, which lets you put in the default value, which in your case is the value from the database:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo set_value('first_name', $row->first_name);?>">
```